react-bootstrap Modal Button Not respected
When using modal in  Nextjs React-Bootstrap + RTL the button bottom appear on the right and not on the left as it should.
I tried to add the rtl as the doc shows with out luck.
Here is my code example...
export default function StaticExample() {
  return (
    <div
      className="modal show"
      style={{ display: "block", position: "initial" }}
    >
      <Modal.Dialog size="xl">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Row className="mb-3">
              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
                <Form.Label>דוא״ל</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  size="sm"
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Row>

            <Row className="mb-3">
              <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
                <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select defaultValue="Choose...">
                  <option>Choose...</option>
                  <option>...</option>
                </Form.Select>
              </Form.Group>
            </Row>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" id="formGridCheckbox">
              <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal.Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

